# React change components on setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

for the first 3 seconds it should show `LoadingActive` component, after that it should disappear and show `LoadingFailed` and on Button press it should again show `LoadingActive` 3s and than `LoadingFailed`. How can i do the part where onPress the cycle repeats one more time?

```
export function Loading() {
    const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        setShowComponent(!showComponent);
    }, 3000);
}, []);

return (
        <View>
            {showComponent && <LoadingFailed />}
            {!showComponent && <LoadingActive />}
        </View>
);
}

function LoadingActive() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>
            Loading
        </Text>
    </View>
);
}

function LoadingFailed() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>
            Failure
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={} title='RETRY' /> //On press should again show  `LoadingActive` 3s and than `LoadingFailed`
    </View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need a single timeout every time use `setTimeout` and let `useEffect` initialize it every time that the `loading` state changes to `true`:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Loading() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;
    
    if(loading) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        timeout = setLoading(false);
      }, 3000);
    }
    
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  }, [loading]);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading 
        ? <LoadingActive /> 
        : <LoadingFailed reload={() => setLoading(true)} />
      }
    </div>
  );
}

function LoadingActive() {
  return (
    <div>
      Loading
    </div>
  );
}

function LoadingFailed({ reload }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button title='RETRY' onClick={reload}>Retry</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Loading />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, but before all of this renders in the beginning i need that for 3seconds it shows LoadingActive. Right now at the beginning it shows LoadingFailed

Comment: It shows LoadingActive when it starts (run the code snippet).

Comment: sorry, you are right. It works on the snippet. I should figure out why it doesnt on my React Native code. ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Loading />); this could be the part that i dont have in react native, i think thats why it doesnt start with Loading

Comment: I've reversed the condition to make it more logical. Change active to appear on true and failed on false.